# Node.js + testing: DI vs hard dependencies

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I'm working on some repo. And add refactoring to extract some functionality into class

The question is -- I prefer to use passing dependencies from outside (DI). But I see that it's not common pattern for node.js application.

So the question - is there any good examples ( links to repos ) where guys use DI for providing dependencies.

The opposite opinion is -- "We always can use `proxyquire` module to mock dependencies"

P.S
example for code I propose is

```
// use
const inst = new Cls(getDep1(), getDep2());
// where getDep1 / getDep2 provide dependencies from side modules
```

instead of

```
//Cls
const dep1 = require('dep1');
const dep2 = require('dep2');
module.exports = function Cls() {
  // deps usage
}

// and 
const inst = new Cls();
```

The question is about arguments in node.js related projects

Answer (score 0):

Your example is about as clear as it gets.  If you want to configure a stub/mock in a test for a class dependency without using proxyquire or mockery or some other require patcher, then you have to provide another point of entry into your code.

you could explicitly use DI like in your example:

```
function Cls(dep1, dep2) {
  this.dep1 = dep1;
  this.dep2 = dep2;
}
```

Which could live off by itself, then your calling code would be responsible for importing your class, configuring its dependencies, and instantiating it correctly.  That way your `Cls` is isolated and unit testable itself.

You could also expose the dependencies that need to be handled as public properties:

```
const dep1 = require('dep1');
const dep2 = require('dep2');
module.exports = function Cls() {
   this.dep1 = dep1;
   this.dep2 = dep2;
}
```

That could allow the module that `Cls` is defined in to also contain the code that associates it with its deps, while still allowing your unit tests to easily configure `Cls` with mock/stub objects.  This relies on requires to be side effect free :(

```
var cls = new Cls();
cls.dep1 = new SomeStub();
cls.dep2 = new SomeStub();
cls.exercise();
```